# Android Quickly Find All Local Devices on Network

Tags: android

I'm making an Android app that needs to be able to see local network devices (either names or ip's). Currently I can scan the network and find the local IP's of devices. However it takes so long the user sees a black screen loading for a couple minutes while it searches the network.

Here is the code that I'm currently using:

```
    private ArrayList<String> scanSubNet(String subnet) {
    ArrayList<String> hosts = new ArrayList<String>();

    InetAddress inetAddress = null;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        try {
            inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(subnet + String.valueOf(i));
            if (inetAddress.isReachable(1000)) {
                hosts.add(inetAddress.getHostName());
                Log.d("ERRORID", inetAddress.getHostName());
            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return hosts;
}
```

There has to be a faster way to search for network for devices right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [Using Network Service Discovery](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) and perform task in AsyncTask. Keep on updating the UI when a new node joins your local network.

Comment: when trying to implement their example the line "mDiscoveryListener = new NsdManager.DiscoveryListener()" needs suppressors. Is this because of not being on jelly bean? if so does it mean i cannot use this solution?

Comment: Yes, This API was added in API Level 16. Which is Jellybean.

Comment: I'm going to be changing the API Level to min 16 then. Thanks you very much for the help.